# Gnuradio,OOT: correcting send() for tagged stream block?

Tags: c++, gnuradio, usrp

I need help making a gnuradio OOT module. I am actually trying to extending one code.

I am trying to make 2 TX 1Rx tagged stream block (OOT). For 1Tx 1Rx, it
is working fine. I am trying to extend it. Now the problem is, I am not
being able to configure the send() function. With this code, one transmitter transmits, but other does not work. The subdev specification and frequency and other parameters are allocated correctly. I checked.

If I try make test, it does not show any problem. I checked the every
port of my USRP X310, it is working fine.

Here's the code. I putting a short part which deals with the send and receive buffer.

```
void
usrp_echotimer_cc_impl::send()
{
// Data to USRP
num_tx_samps = d_tx_stream->send(d_in_send1, total_num_samps,
d_metadata_tx, total_num_samps/(float)d_samp_rate+d_timeout_tx);
num_tx_samps = d_tx_stream->send(d_in_send0, total_num_samps,
d_metadata_tx, total_num_samps/(float)d_samp_rate+d_timeout_tx);
}

int
usrp_echotimer_cc_impl::work (int noutput_items,
gr_vector_int &ninput_items,
gr_vector_const_void_star &input_items,
gr_vector_void_star &output_items)
{
gr_complex *in0 = (gr_complex *) input_items[0];
gr_complex *in1 = (gr_complex *) input_items[1];
gr_complex *out = (gr_complex *) output_items[0];
// Set output items on packet length
noutput_items = ninput_items[0]=ninput_items[1];

// Resize output buffer
if(d_out_buffer.size()!=noutput_items)
d_out_buffer.resize(noutput_items);

// Send thread
d_in_send0 = in0;
d_in_send1 = in1;
d_noutput_items_send = noutput_items;
d_thread_send =
gr::thread::thread(boost::bind(&usrp_echotimer_cc_impl::send, this));

// Receive thread
d_out_recv = &d_out_buffer[0];
d_noutput_items_recv = noutput_items;
d_thread_recv =
gr::thread::thread(boost::bind(&usrp_echotimer_cc_impl::receive, this));
```

My system config is X310, daughterboard SBX-120 and I am using UHD-3.9. I checked the subdev specification, gain and frequency assignment. Those
are fine.

Comment: Sanjoy, there's active discussion about this exact email you wrote on the mailing list: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2015-06/msg00461.html

I have sent you a multi-page answer and pointed out several mistakes, and Martin asked for more clarification. I think it would be wise to answer his question first before asking elsewhere.

Comment: I'm regretfully downvoting, for the undeclared cross-posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For completeness:**
This has been asked yesterday on the GNU Radio mailing list; Sanjoy has already gotten two responses:

Martin Braun wrote:

> Sorry, Sanjoy,
>
> we'll need some more information before we can give you better
>   feedback. It's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve, and
>   what exactly is failing.
>
> Perhaps this helps getting started:
>   http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/ReportingErrors
>
> Cheers, Martin

And my answer is a bit longish, but it's available [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2015-06/msg00471.html). In excerpts:

> Hi Sanjoy,
>
> > I am trying to make 2 TX 1Rx tagged stream block(OOT). For 1Tx 1Rx, it was working fine. I am trying to extend it. Now the problem is, I
> >     am not being able to configure the send() function.
>
> Is there a
>   particular reason you're creating your own block? Is there a feature
>   missing on the USRP sink and source that come with gr-uhd?

...

> your send() function looks a bit strange; what you're doing is
>   transmitting two things on a single channel after each other. Also,
>   what you should be doing (from a programming style point of view) is
>   pass the buffers you want to send as references or something, but not
>   save them to class properties and then call send(). To send two
>   buffers to two different channels, you will need to use a vector
>   containing the two buffers -- have a look at rx_multi_samples; that of
>   course recv()s rather  than sends(), but the semantics are the same.

...

> noutput_items is given to you to let your work now how much it may produce, that's why it's a parameter.

...

> There's no reason GNU Radio couldn't already call your work function again while usrp_echotimer_cc_impl::send() hasn't even started to transmit samples. Then, your d_send variables will be overwritten.

...

> Since a single X310 is inherently coherent and has the same time, you can simply use a USRP sink and a source, use set_start_time(...) on both with the same time spec, and have your flow graph consume and produce samples in different threads, coherently.